# PHP open link and then execute function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I recently started building a login system using php and mysql database.
Right now I have already built this using php code and data typed by user in a bootstrap modal.

User opens his mailbox, click a link which executes verification script in database to set user as verified and load my main site page.

After that I would like to add some modal to tell something like "Your account was verified" just once. What is a right way to do it? I thought that it can be done by php by running jquery function located in `index.php` like

```
<?php
    header('location:index.php');
    echo "<script> $('#addText').modal();</script>";
?>
```

But as I can see it is not correct and php just loads `index.php` and that's all.

P.S. I am sorry for my ignorance of php fundamentals.

Comment: Do you want this modal to open before redirecting to index or after?

Comment: If you add a header with location, the browser will redirect the user to that location instantly. Responses with redirects can't contain any body. One solution would be to remove that header, add a "ok"  (or what you want to call it) button on the modal and redirect using javascript when they click the button.

Comment: @El_Vanja after. When account is completely verified in mysql db a main page should be loaded and after thet a modal appear

Comment: In that case you would need to pass a parameter to tell the page it should display the modal. A session variable would make sense here, since it wouldn't reveal the parameter in the URL.

Comment: You don't need to show any modals for a cleaner UX. If a login or registration passed - it passed. No need to bother your users for something that is already obvious. And yeah, use Session variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an HTTP redirect, the contents of the page are ignored.

Instead, you can use a meta-refresh tag, which allows delaying the redirect.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=https://example.com/index.php" />
<script src="js/jquery.js">
<script> $(function() {$('#addText').modal();})</script>
</head>
```

`5;` means to delay the refresh for 5 seconds.